# Converting a particular cell in a column of type varchar to nvarchar

Tags: sql, ssms, varchar, nvarchar

I have a table tblemp with column 'value'  of type 'varchar' in that column i have a cell named 'bankname' . I want to make 'bankname' of type nvarchar. How can i do that?

Comment: Tables have columns. Is bankname a column?

Comment: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-alter-table-alter-column/

Comment: Columns have datatypes not "cells". Cells do no exist in SQL Server; that's something you'll find in a (Excel) worksheet. A single column can only contain one datatype, not many. If you want to change the data type of a value stored in a column, you have to change the **entire** column. If you are mixing data types in a column, you have a design flaw and should likely have 2+ columns (1 for each different type of data item).